# Inverse of $aI - \frac{a}{b}J$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

How would I find the inverse of this matrix?

I know we can pull the a out so that:

\begin{equation}
aI - \frac{a}{b}J = a\left[I - \frac{1}{b}J\right]
\end{equation}

and then we can focus on the inverse of the matrix in the brackets, but this seems to be outside the scope of how I know how to invert a matrix.

Comment: Is $J$ the all-ones matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $J^2 = nJ$, when $J$ is of order $n \times n$.

Then $(I - rJ)(I - sJ) = I - (r + s)J + rs J^2 = I + (nrs - r - s)J$.

Now, for any given $r$, we can find $s$ such that the above becomes $I$ by solving $nrs - r - s = 0$. That is, $s = \frac{r}{nr - 1}$. This does not work if $r = \frac 1 n$. But when $r = \frac 1 n$, we have $I - rJ = I - \frac 1 n J$, which is non-invertible — there are multiple ways to see this — observe that it is idempotent (but is not the identity matrix, and therefore must be singular), or observe that $0$ is an eigenvalue, since $n$ is an eigenvalue of $J$.

Thus, for any $r \ne \frac 1 n$, $(I - rJ)^{-1} = I - \frac{r}{nr - 1}J$.

Therefore, $$\left(a - \dfrac a b J\right)^{-1} = \dfrac 1 a I - \dfrac{1}{a(n - b)} J$$ for any $a \ne 0, b \ne n$.